# Group 2 or more fields on mongodb on C# using Mongo Driver

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to group 3 fields "GameName", "MinBet" and "Time", if data saved on a SQLDb, I just need use `WorkScope.GetAll<Game>().GroupBy(s=> new {s.GameName,s.MinBet,s.Time})` then select data to return. But this data saved on Mongo so I cant group like that.
 I have try

```
var query1 = Mongo.GetAll<History>("history").AsQueryable().GroupBy(s=>new GroupBy( s.GameName, s.MinBet, s.Time )).Select(s => new
            {
                GameId = s.First().GameId,
                GameName = s.Key.GameName,
                MinBet = s.Key.MinBet,
                Time = s.Key.Time,
                TotalWin = s.Where(s => s.WinAmount == 0).Sum(s => s.BetAmount),
                TotalLose = s.Sum(s => s.WinAmount),                  
            }).ToList();
```

And

```
var query=Mongo.GetAll<History>("history")
                .Aggregate()
                .Group(
                        s=> new GroupBy
                        (
                            s.GameName,
                            s.MinBet,
                            s.Time
                        ),
                        z=> new
                        {
                            Key=z.Key,                    
                            TotalWin = z.Where(s => s.WinAmount == 0).Sum(s => s.BetAmount),
                            TotalLose = z.Sum(s => s.WinAmount),                               
                            GameId=z.First().Fee
                        }

                    )
                .Project(s=> new
                {
                    GameId=s.GameId,
                    GameName=s.Key.GameName,
                    MinBet=s.Key.MinBet,
                    Time=s.Key.Time,
                    TotalWin=s.TotalWin,
                    TotalLose=s.TotalLose,                        
                }).ToList()
                ;
```

It alaways return `MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: No matching creator found.`
How can I group it to have right data like SqlDb.

Comment: I didn't look on your query deeply, but this error  `No matching creator found.` most likely means that you received the server response, but the returned bson document cannot be converted into History or nested classes in this class

Comment: so you should look at the proper serialization configuration. Try to avoid using dynamic classes in the projection